Psi Probe tomcat 10
Good evening,
I've migrated from tomcat 9 to tomcat 10 my java application and Psi probe is no longer working. Tried to deploy probe.war version 5.0.0 with /probe context but nothing happens when calling web page of probe.Any idea to solve this issue?
Thank you

latest war
java 21
apache-tomcat-10.1.34
export the paths properly.
worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
